# Cross platform apps with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mono, cross-platform

I'm thinking of developing a desktop app in C#. Although windows will be my main target, later I'll try and run the app in MacOS X and linux. Can I do this today, in a simple way?
I'm aware of the mono project, but it is not clear to me if I can do this in a simple way.

Also, what is the relation between WPF and Silverlight? AFAIK Silverlight follows a plugin model much like Flash or Java. Can I develop my desktop app with Silverlight and deploy it on windows, linux and os x without much changes?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Silverlight doesn't actually have that much in common with WPF. WPF is a framework for building desktop apps, Silverlight is a browser plugin, much like Flash. Silverlight applications can be run across Windows and Mac OS X natively, and through Mono's Moonlight project on Linux.

Comment: "Silverlight doesn't actually have that much in common with WPF" : I wouldn't say that... they do have much in common ! the XAML language, the DependencyObject model, most controls... There are a few WPF features that are not available in Silverlight, and a few Silverlight features not available in WPF, but the gap is getting smaller with the latest version of both products

Comment: Thomas is right. Moreover, Microsoft are explicitly aiming to *converge* the WPF/Silverlight frameworks so that in time they will be virtually fully interopable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Mono project does not support .Net 3 and WPF yet, and it will probably been some time before that happens.

Silverlight might be sufficient for your needs. 
As of Silverlight 3.0 you can run Silverlight outside the browser, even create a shortcut to it on the desktop.

Comment: NB: Moonlight currently only stably supports Silverlight 1.0, and only has a pre-alpha release of 2.0.

Comment: Mono does support a number of .net 3.x capabilities, but not WPF.

Comment: As Supercheetah said, the monoproject (moonlight) does only fully support SL 1.0, and partially SL 2.0. But if you need to win SL outside the browser then they can only run on Mac and Windows. If you really need to support linux, you may have to look into other technologies, such as Adobe AIR or Java Applet.

Answer (score 2):

Last I heard, the Mono project has no plans to implement WPF, however they are working on other .NET 3.5 features, especially LINQ and ASP.NET MVC.  The problem with implementing WPF in Mono (beyond the size and complexity of the API) is that on Windows it uses DirectX for rendering, so an implementation for Mono would need to use OpenGL.  Definitely not a trivial undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is used to build desktop applications for **Windows only**. Currently no other platforms are supported. If cross-platform support is a must, you can create a browser-based application and use Silverlight. Silverlight runs applications in the browser, though, so you cannot make a "desktop" application using that.

Comment: You can make applications that run outside of browser with Silverlight 3. However, they are still limited by Silverlight sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Mono is working hard to make sure that Silverlight runs cross platform (as mentioned on one of the stack overflow podcasts).  So that seems to be a good way to go.